# Node.js: Is there a way to detect whether I'm using bash or cmd?

Tags: bash

So, I'm messing around with an open source node application and I'm getting errors when I ask it to run a "command line" command. The original programmer wrote it in such a way that it only detects the os. If it's Windows it appends cmd, else it appends bash to run the command.
The problem is that I'm using Bash, on Windows, and the original author must not have thought of this..

Is there a way to get Node to detect where it's being run from, as opposed to detecting the os?

Comment: What does the shell it's invoked from have to do with the shell it invokes when it calls an external command? On UNIX, for example, any attempt to start a subshell using `system()` or equivalents **always** uses `/bin/sh`, no matter if the user is using bash, ksh, csh, fish, or something completely different (such as starting directly via `execve()` from a native executable with no shell involved at all).  Can you provide a [mcve] that lets others reproduce the failure, when using `cmd` when run from bash on Windows?

Comment: ...now, if you're actually trying to, say, distinguish between a Cygwin-compiled version of Node and a native-win32 Node build, that would make much more sense.

Comment: The app runs shell commands from inside the app, so it needs to be appended with bash or cmd to run the command.

Comment: This is basically the code:
    var isWin = /^win/.test(process.platform)
    var cmd = command
    if (isWin) {
      cmd = 'cmd /C "' + command + '"'
    } else {
      cmd = 'bash -c "' + command + '"'
    }

Comment: You could get the output of the `type -p bash` in node and get the path. If the path is not **/bin/bash** it could be windows, but I'm not familiar with bash on windows

Comment: Or possibly `echo $PATH`  and regex for "Windows" or "System32"

Comment: [link]https://gist.github.com/Fliktrax/8e1aed6719dd66749c37290bd01cd662

Comment: That last one did the trick, thanks! The others failed. I was also trying to use "process.env.SHELL" but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: I'll add as answer if it worked for you. As I'm not familiar with bash on Windows or have any Microsoft products,  I have no way of verifying.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a perfect solution but I personally check if `ls` gives (`stderr`) an error. I use spawn to run that in a child process to avoid outputting anything in the current process.

You should know that for some reason, even though `ls` is a valid command in PowerShell, it will also output an error when run via `child_process` execution methods within a PowerShell CLI. This strange behavior is useful to detect both CMD and PowerShell.

Lastly, it still allows the end-user to use a bash-like CLI under Windows since in that case, `ls` will work just fine (and not throw any error). Here is the function:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process')
const os = require('os')

function isCmd() {
  if (os.platform() !== 'win32') {
    return false
  }

  try {
    const result = spawnSync(`ls`, {
      stdio: 'pipe',
    })

    return result.error !== undefined
  } catch (err) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Windows" of "System32" are in your PATH env variables:

[Updated Gist](https://gist.github.com/Fliktrax/8e1aed6719dd66749c37290bd01cd662)

Comment: It didn't quite work, but it set me on the right track. I ended up with the function: 
function winBash(){
  var bashos = 'windows';
  var path=process.env.PATH;
    if( (path.indexOf('\\usr\\bifn') > -1)) {
      return bashos
    }
}